# Running an event that monitors a file change in Windows Server 2012

Tags: powershell, server, task, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2012

I am trying to figure out how to create a trigger in Windows Server 2012 task scheduler. I have noticed there is a 'On an event' option in the 'Begin the task' drop down list. However I can't figure out how to set this up with the documentation available.

The idea is to monitor the file with some Powershell script.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does anyone know how to setup a trigger using an 'on an event'?

Comment: Please see this thread (trigger a task based on an event): http://serverfault.com/q/277450/369115